Error connecting and JMSListener not starting with deploying API Manager
While I am starting up the api manager I keep running into the same error (Shown at end of questions).
I had been working with our enterprise security team and I have full access to all of our ports, the error they see is coming through Port 5353 where we block for mDNS poisoning, but WSO2 does not call that port.  We even tried moving all of the ports up by one (which is why it is showing 9712 and not 9711) and I have reinstalled my Java in case it was something to do with that.  Does anyone have any other ideas we can try?  I will need full access by the end of the month and this is the last thing that keeps blocking me.
Thank you for all of your help!
Current Error:
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,311] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,311] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,316] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,316] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,321] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,321] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,322] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,322] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,322] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,322] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,324] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,324] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,324] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,324] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,325] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,325] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,325] ERROR - JMSListener JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2024-04-03 10:55:23,325] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2024-04-03 10:55:53,038]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at URL Endpoint/Endpoints [tcp://192.168.40.6:9612], will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2024-04-03 10:55:53,039] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.40.6:9712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.40.6:9712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) [?:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 192.168.40.6:9712. Permission denied: connect
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:75) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:163) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        ... 6 more


We have tried reinstalling Java, Checking the port logs and permissions, and moving all of the ports up by 1 to see if that would change the error at all.

Can you share the environment (os, etc.) and jdk details?

Of course!  I am running on Windows 10 and JDK 17

This could be a restriction put forth by the OS itself on ports. I could find some similar concerns raised by googling. Can you check the OS level configs?

I do not believe that it is an OS block.  I am able to connect to api manager fine when I am in the office, but when I remote in using a VPN it brings up those errors.  It is almost like there is a location block on it.
